# Are UNIX_TIMESTAMP() and time() the same

Tags: php, mysql, unix, timestamp

Does MySQL UNIX_TIMESTAMP() show the same UNIX timestamp as PHP's time() function. Even when the servers are in two different locations?

I've been looking into time and date for hours now and I've confused the hell out of my self.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they are the same.

UNIX timestamps are the number of seconds since midnight of January 1, 1970 in UTC. That is the same time in history no matter where you are, no matter what time zone you're in. The time elapsed since then is the same on every system with an accurate clock.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the clarification. So, if it's a botched clock it'll be different?

Comment: Well, on any system where the computer thinks it's a different time than it really is, any datetime code would give you the wrong time. It it's 5PM but you told your computer's clock it's 4PM, every time it gives you will be an hour behind.

Comment: Oh okay. That is completely out of my hands then. Thanks again.

Comment: Regarding Dan's comment: This problem will be compounded if you're running MySQL on a separate server to your PHP code. If that's the case it's almost certain they'll report different times to each other (even if only slightly different).